# Proving that the identity $e$ of $G$ is in the subgroup $H_a$

Tags: group-theory

I have the given group, $H_a=\{x\in G \mid xa=ax \}$, and I want to prove it is a subgroup of $G$.

The associative law of $ax=xa$ proves  that the binary operation of $G$ is closed in $H_a$. But when proving that the identity $e$ of $G$ is in $H_a$, I do $a\cdot0=0$. But how do I know that $0\in G$?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you do "$a\cdot0=0$"? Where does the $0$ come from?

Comment: Every group has a neutral element, this is always unique. Since all elements of $H$ must be in $G$, the only possible neutral element of $H$ is $e$ , the neutral element of $G$.

Comment: Isn't e = 0  neutral?

Comment: Check it $C_G (a)\le G $ .

Comment: @vqngs If $e=0$ is the identity element, then $a\cdot0=a$ not $a\cdot0=0$...

Comment: Noted, thanks. I am used to the mathematical product of a times 0

Comment: I have closed this question as a duplicate of a question asking is $Z(G)\leq G$, as the accepted answer here just proves this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $a\in G$.

Use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20one,is%20also%20in%20the%20subset.).

We have $ea=a=ae$ by definition of $e$. Thus $e\in H_a$, so $H_a\neq\varnothing$.

By definition, $H_a\subseteq G$.

Let $x,y\in H_a$. Then we have $xa=ax$ and $ya=ay$; in particular, we have $ay^{-1}=y^{-1}a$ by multiplying on both sides of $ya=ay$ by $y^{-1}$. Now

$$\begin{align}
(xy^{-1})a&=x(y^{-1}a)\\
&=x(ay^{-1})\\
&=(xa)y^{-1}\\
&=(ax)y^{-1}\\
&=a(xy^{-1}),
\end{align}$$

so $xy^{-1}\in H_a$.

Hence $H_a\le G$.

Answer (score 1):

The identity element satisfies $ae=ea$ and so belongs to $H_a$.

There is no absorbing element in a group such as $0$ with $a0=0$.

Comment: I am puzzled by the correct point of user1729 that $a\cdot0=a$ . I can't find this operation in my book, explained in detail. What is this operator $\cdot$ called? Eventually, if it is a regular dot product, why is it a and not 0?

Comment: @vqngs The operation $\cdot$ simply denotes the operation in the group $G$. This operation varies from group to group. (Confusingly, we do often refer to it as "multiplication" although it is not in general multiplication of numbers...)

Comment: *"There is no absorbing element in a group such as $0$ with $a0=0$"* Well, unless $G=\{0\}$ . . .

Comment: @user1729 Thanks. Does it have a name?

Comment: The centralizer of a subset S of group G is defined as $C_G(S) = \{g\in G\mid gs=sg\forall s\in S\}$.

Comment: @vqngs Sort of. Groups are abstract, and we often call the *abstract* operation "multiplication". For example, we might say "when we multiply an element $g$ by the identity $e$ we get $g$ again", and we write $g\cdot e=g$. However, the operation in the group could be *anything*, and is not necessarily multiplication of numbers.

Comment: @user1729 . Thanks!